# htaccess redirect from asp to php with parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have to redirect all my asp page to new website developed in PHP.

I had my asp page as,
`abc.asp?id=82`

Which need to be redirected to
`siteurl/index.php/abc`

Can any one help me with this in HTAccess?

I have tried with,
`Redirect 301 /abc.asp?id=82 siteurl/index.php/abc`

`rewriterule ^/abc.asp?id=82$ siteurl/index.php/abc[R=301,L]`

But this is not working and giving me a 404 error.

Comment: You have `abc.asp` in your rewrite rule while as per your example you want to redirect `content.asp` ?

Comment: Do you want to redirect content.asp page to new site url ?

Comment: it was my mistake .its not content.asp page which i need to redirect.the needed page is abc.asp?id=82

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't match against the query string in either a `Redirect` or `RewriteRule`. It's not very clear what the scope you're trying to accomplish here. Is the `id=82` important? Does `abc` mean "anything that's just letters"? Is `siteurl` a directory or a domain name? If it's strictly what you've attempted, then this is strictly how it'll work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=82($|&)
RewriteRule ^/?abc.asp$ siteurl/index.php/abc? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Yes we have to strictly follow this as our old site was in asp and we don't want to send our user to "Page not found" page.

Comment: Above is working for me but it is attaching querysting as it was given in the RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=82($|&).Does this has any other way?

Comment: @ArpiPatel Sorry, left out the `?` at the end of the rule

Answer (score 1):

You're making 2 main mistakes:

1. Rewrite rule matches only URI part and doesn't match query string
2. Rewrite rule in .htaccess doesn't match leading slash.

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=82(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(abc)\.asp$ http://domain.com/index.php/$1 [R=302,L,NC]
```

Once you verify it to be working replace 302 (Temporary Redirect) with 301 (Permanent Redirect)

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
RewriteRule ^abc.asp$ siteurl/index.php/abc [R=301,QSA,L]
```

That should do the job.. Using the `QSA` flag will forward any GET paramater too, if that's what you meant with the title.